# Ubuntu not booting on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, ssd

I have an SSD which I installed both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.1. When I installed Ubuntu I allocated 500 MB to /boot and the rest of the Ubuntu partition to /. The installation completed and now when I reboot it shows me a screen with a purple border and black screen. Then after that it goes to a black screen and nothing happens.

I have a Nvidia GTX 780, Intel i7 and a Gigabyte H97-HD3 motherboard.

Comment: Also I can't even boot into Windows 7!

Comment: Try holding down Shift during boot, this should let you get access to the GRUB menu. Did you install drivers at all during the installation process? As for the purple border + black box - that's normal, its just GRUB not showing up for faster boot times.

Comment: I did get to the GRUB menu and loaded Ubuntu. All I got was a flash white underline against a black background. I didn't install any drivers. Also will I be able to get back into Windows 7? Thank you

Comment: Okay. In what order did you install the OSes? Was Windows already installed, or did you install it right before or right after Ubuntu? Did any text show up when it was the white cursor on the black background? Was there anything else on the GRUB menu?

Comment: Windows 7 and then Ubuntu. I installed Windows 7 and the next day later, today, I installed Ubuntu. No text at all with the white cursor, and after I pressed shift and go into the GRUB menu all there was Ubuntu, System something, and something else. No mention of Windows or anything. It was purple and normal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to download this [boot repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) iso and burn it to a CD-Rom then boot to it and run the Boot Repair utility. Be sure to copy down the boot-repair url when you get the report so in case it does not work, you can post the URL here and one of us can analyze it for you.

My previous answer, which was nearly identical to this one was deleted by "Mitch" for reasons I can only speculate about after reading the advice in the help center.  I'm guessing my SIN was to speculate as to the cause of the failure, regardless of whether I actually helped the user in need.

I have removed all speculation about what may have caused the failure.  I suppose I must try to be less EDUCATIONAL in my use of this site.  It's not how I'd run this site, but then, I don't run this site.